# Driver and corrective shapes issue

Tags: drivers

say I have a bone that rotates between -45° and 45°. There is a way to make a driver that applies shape_A between -45° and 0°, and shape_B between 0° and 45° ?
Or do I have to create two different drivers?
I'm a bit confused, thanks for any hint.

Comment: You can write a driver that uses a test to set a shapekey to 0 in one case and 1 in the other.

Comment: I hope you don't mean a pregnancy test... ;) i would use an if statement... ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add 3 shapekeys.

[image]

Add a driver to the 2nd shape key value like this:

[image]

```
1 if var > 0 else 0
```

Do the same for the 3rd shape key value but with this shape key value:

```
1 if var > 0 else 0
```

then you get:

[image]

```
Note: I made this here for a simple cube. But this works with bones as well.
```

---

```
Note 2: You can make smoother transitions by using these drivers:

    pi/4*abs(var) if var < 0 else 0
    pi/4*var if var > 0 else 0
```

Smooth result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris, really appreciated, I'm gonna try this right away!

Comment: If it helps you, please check the checkmark left to my answer. If you still have questions, just add a comment.

Comment: I tried and it works perfectly. Checked the marks! Thanks again.

Comment: Glad I could help